# Is it possible to use image web URL instead of local pin image for map view control in Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

I tried to assign image url like 'http://someimageurl.png' to the selectedImage & unSelectedImage properties while adding pin to the map view control.
But, still showing the default image.

Is there a way to use image url for pin rather than local resource image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use a url for pin images on map object.
You can use that kind of image url's for image object, but not for map object.

Comment: Is there any work around for this. I want to show hotel prices instead of pins. Any possibility? Normal google maps for desktop, it is happening.